# Program has to wait till two threads (Sql query execution) are completed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, qthread, pyside2

I have a program which compares to DB table values and i have created a GUI in PyQt5. I have created two threads one for querying each table and then program has to wait till two threads are completed. My code below

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from Main_interface import Ui_mainWindow
import pandas as pd


class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):

  sqlClicked1 = QtCore.Signal(str)
  sqlClicked2 = QtCore.Signal(str)

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
    self.thread.start()
    self.obj = Worker()
    self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
    self.sqlClicked.connect(self.obj.runsql_MC)
    self.sqlClicked1.connect(self.obj.runsql_IRI)
    self.obj.error.connect(self.on_error)


 def run_report(self):
    sqlquery1 = "Select * from table1"
    sqlquery2 = "Select * from table2"

    df1 = self.sqlClicked1.emit(sqlquery1)
    df2 = self.sqlClicked2.emit(sqlquery2)

    self.sqlClicked1.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
    self.sqlClicked2.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

    print("SQL execution is done")

    #Then i am calling function to compare two dataframes


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
   finished = QtCore.Signal()
   result = QtCore.Signal(object)

   @QtCore.Slot(str)
   def runsql_MC(self, sqlquery_MC):
     print("Thread1 is working")
     try:
        df1 = pd.read_sql(sql=sqlquery_MC, con=cnxn)
     except:
        traceback.print_exc()
     else:
        self.signals.result.emit(df1)  # Return the result of the processing
     finally:
        self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done

  @QtCore.Slot(str)
  def runsql_IRI(self, sqlquery_IRI):
    print("Thread2 is working")
    try:
        df2 = pd.read_sql(sql=sqlquery_IRI, con=cnxn)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        self.signals.result.emit(df2)  
    finally:
        self.signals.finished.emit()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  my_app = mainWindow()
  my_app.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`self.sqlClicked1.emit(sqlquery1)` and `self.sqlClicked2.emit(sqlquery2)` is calling corresponding threads `runsql_MC()` and `runsql_IRI`. Then I need to wait till two threads are completed to start comparison process. Currently its not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your code is not an MRE, show your ignorance of various concepts.

- The emission of a signal does not imply obtaining the data as a result since it will be sent asynchronously.
- In your code even if you invoke 2 queries does not imply that each one runs on different threads since the worker lives in a single thread.
- Your runsql_MC and runsql_IRI methods are redundant since they are a template of the same thing.
- In addition to other errors such as that there is no object/signal called sqlClicked, you have not declared the object signals, etc.

The idea is to have a worker who lives in a different thread for each query, and create a class that handles the workers waiting for the data and eliminating when they have finished their work.

```py
from functools import partial
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.Signal()
    result = QtCore.Signal(object)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def runsql(self, query):
        cnxn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        print("Thread1 is working")
        try:
            df1 = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=cnxn)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        else:
            self.result.emit(df1)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.finished.emit()  # Done


class SqlManager(QtCore.QObject):
    results = QtCore.Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.workers_and_threads = {}
        self.dataframes = []

    def execute_queries(self, queries):
        for query in queries:
            thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
            thread.start()
            worker = Worker()
            worker.result.connect(self.onResults)
            worker.moveToThread(thread)
            self.workers_and_threads[worker] = thread
            # launch task
            wrapper = partial(worker.runsql, query)
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)

    @QtCore.Slot(object)
    def onResults(self, result):
        worker = self.sender()
        thread = self.workers_and_threads[worker]
        thread.quit()
        thread.wait()
        del self.workers_and_threads[worker]
        worker.deleteLater()
        self.dataframes.append(result)
        if not self.workers_and_threads:
            self.results.emit(self.dataframes)
            self.dataframes = []


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.push_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Run Report")
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.run_report)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.push_button)

        self.manager = SqlManager(self)
        self.manager.results.connect(self.onResults)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def run_report(self):
        sqlquery1 = "Select * from table1"
        sqlquery2 = "Select * from table2"
        queries = [sqlquery1, sqlquery2]
        self.manager.execute_queries(queries)
        self.push_button.setEnabled(False)

    @QtCore.Slot(list)
    def onResults(self, dataframes):
        print(dataframes)
        self.push_button.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_app = MainWindow()
    my_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I made modifications to the code based on your solution. Though it is working fine. My UI goes to not responding state. Can you please look into my code if I have made any mistakes. Code: https://gist.github.com/arvinthin/0b2906e8a9f6fbe050056aa2a67c9d4f

Comment: Sorry for reporting the issue after a while. UI goes to not responding state if SQL query runs for long time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if it is written in your code but Have you ever uses a [***join()***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) sentence to wait till those threads end? You should be using it when you awake those two threads inside your `def __init__()` method from your `mainWindow` class

Comment: I am not sure how to write join() sentence in PyQT to wait until both threads end